# Noir uberjar only works in build directory

Tags: clojure, leiningen, noir

I am attempting to distribute a small web application build with the clojure web framework noir. It works as expected when run with `lein run`. When I run `lein uberjar` and then `java -jar project-1.0.0-standalone.jar` it works as expected. However, if I move the jar file (project-1.0.0-standalone.jar) it runs, but every page results in a 404. My `project.clj` is the default one generated by `lein noir new` except I added `:omit-source true` and `:aot :all`.

I'm using:

leiningen 1.7.1

clojure 1.2.1

noir 1.2.1

How can I make a jar that can be distributed to others without source?

Comment: Why does it not work (every page returns 404) when I move the jar file to another location (on the same computer)?

Answer (score 0):

if you have not already added `gen-class`  calls to your namespace definitions, adding them may fix this. You can test this by running

```
  lein clean
  lein compile
```

and make sure you see each of your classes being built

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is because of the way noir.server/load-views requires the namespaces. If you move it from the target/ directory, it can no longer find the views directory you passed into load-views.

The workaround is to explicitly require all you're views in lieu of using the load-views function. Then you should be able run the uberjar anywhere.